# Android: How to save videos played in VideoView into gallery?

Tags: save, android-gallery, android-videoview

I have developed an app that allows play video using VideoView. I could select videos from gallery and play. I would like to know how to save this played videos into gallery with a "Save Video" button. Can anyone guide me through this. My codings are as follows.

AndroidVideoPlayer.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class AndroidVideoPlayer extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
Button button, button2, button3;
VideoView videoView;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_video_player);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savevideo);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearvideo);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });



    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //videoView.starteraser();
            videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //clearimage();
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sample Answer Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        }


    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);
        videoView.start();
    }

}


}
```

activity_android_video_player.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="- PLAY Video -"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/savevideo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="- Save Video -"
/>


<VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help/suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you.